# Pyspark: regex search with text in a list withColumn

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark and I am having a silly "what's-the-best-approach" issue. Basically, I have a map(dict) that I would like to loop over. During each iteration, I want to search through a column in a spark dataframe using `rlike` regex and assign the key of the dict to a new column using `withColumn`

```
maps = {"groceries": ["hot chocolate", "milk", "sugar", "flour"],
        "laundry": ["soap", "detergent", "fabric softener"]
}
```

The data sample is shown below

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|                  id|item_bought|
+--------------------+-----------+
|uiq7Zq52Bww4pZXc3xri|       Soap|
|fpJatwxTeObcbuJH25UI|  Detergent|
|MdK1q5gBygIGFYyvbz8J|       Milk|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

I want to get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+-----------+---------+
|                  id|item_bought|    class|
+--------------------+-----------+---------+
|uiq7Zq52Bww4pZXc3xri|       Soap|  Laundry|
|fpJatwxTeObcbuJH25UI|  Detergent|  Laundry|
|MdK1q5gBygIGFYyvbz8J|       Milk|Groceries|
+--------------------+-----------+---------+
```

I have over 100M records and I want an approach that uses Spark's best practices (distributed computing). One approach that comes to mind is to loop through the map and use `rlike` or `str.contains` for the regex search as shown below:

```
for key, value in maps.items():
    pattern = '|'.join([f'(?i){x}' for x in value]). # ignore case
    df.withColumn("class", col("item_bought").rlike(pattern))
```

But this returns `true` or `false` for the rlike search. I want to substitute the true or false with the `key` value.

Also, considering that I have 100M (up to 150M) records, is looping through the map the best approach?

**EDIT**

What if the `items_bought` in the `df` had special characters (or some extra text)?

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                  id|     item_bought|
+--------------------+----------------+
|uiq7Zq52Bww4pZXc3xri|   Soap -&ju10kg|
|fpJatwxTeObcbuJH25UI|Detergent x.ju2i|
|MdK1q5gBygIGFYyvbz8J|            Milk|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

I don't wanna do a text clean up first, just assign classes based on regex keyword search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With you situation, I will turn the map into a dataframe. I assume the resultant dataframe will be relatively small. Use abroadcast join. What this does is that it distribute the small df to each worker node avoiding a shuffle.

```
#Create df from maps
    df_ref = spark.createDataFrame(maps.items(), schema =('class','item_bought')).withColumn('item_bought',explode('item_bought')).withColumn('item_bought', initcap('item_bought'))

#Broadcast join    
    df.join(broadcast(df_ref), how='left', on='item_bought').show()


+-----------+--------------------+---------+
|item_bought|                  id|    class|
+-----------+--------------------+---------+
|       Soap|uiq7Zq52Bww4pZXc3xri|  laundry|
|  Detergent|fpJatwxTeObcbuJH25UI|  laundry|
|       Milk|MdK1q5gBygIGFYyvbz8J|groceries|
+-----------+--------------------+---------+
```

Following your edit

```
df_ref = spark.createDataFrame(maps.items(), schema =('class','item_bought1')).withColumn('item_bought1',explode('item_bought1')).withColumn('item_bought1', initcap('item_bought1'))


df.withColumn('item_bought1',regexp_extract('item_bought','^[A-Za-z]+',0)).join(broadcast(df_ref), how='left', on='item_bought1').show()

+------------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
|item_bought1|                  id|     item_bought|    class|
+------------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
|        Soap|uiq7Zq52Bww4pZXc3xri|            Soap|  laundry|
|   Detergent|fpJatwxTeObcbuJH25UI|       Detergent|  laundry|
|        Milk|MdK1q5gBygIGFYyvbz8J|            Milk|groceries|
|        Soap|uiq7Zq52Bww4pZXc3xri|   Soap -&ju10kg|  laundry|
|   Detergent|fpJatwxTeObcbuJH25UI|Detergent x.ju2i|  laundry|
|        Milk|MdK1q5gBygIGFYyvbz8J|            Milk|groceries|
```

+------------+--------------------+----------------+---------+

Comment: Thanks @wwnde Would this still work if the `items_bought` were not exact matches? Please see question update.

Comment: What do you mean by exact matches, examples?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the examples

Comment: Regex the main df and then broadcast join

Comment: @deramos please accept the answer if it has solved your problems